# Add DataFrame column with particular numeric index, not in-place

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe whose columns are numeric indexes, which aren't necessarily contiguous. I want to add a new column to it with a particular index, similar to:

```
df[4] = [1,2,3,4]
```

But without modifying the existing dataframe. `df.assign` only accepts kwargs (it can't be directly passed an actual dictionary), and even the (rather kludgy anyway) method of expanding a non-str-keyed dict as kwargs is explicitly guarded against:

```
>>> df.assign(**{4: [1,2,3,4]})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: assign() keywords must be strings
```

Using `pd.concat` *works*, but has a lot of line noise:

```
>>> a
   4  0  1  2  3
0  1  1  2  3  4
1  2  2  3  5  4
>>> pd.concat([a, pd.DataFrame({6: [1,2]})], axis=1)
   4  0  1  2  3  6
0  1  1  2  3  4  1
1  2  2  3  5  4  2
```

Is there a nicer way?

Comment: Is the line noise generated by pandas, or just a result value?  IOW, can you do `_ = pd.concat(...)` and get rid of it?

Comment: @PatrickMaupin I mean the command itself is noisy. Something about all three types of closing bracket *in a row*, with the square one repeated doesn't quite strike me as nice looking code.

Comment: Right you are.  Misunderstood; need coffee...  khammel's answer looks a bit better, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join will return a copy instead of affecting the existing dataframe (joins the two dataframes on the matching indexes):

```
>>> a.join(pd.DataFrame({6: [1,2]}))
   4  0  1  2  3  6
0  1  1  2  3  4  1
1  2  2  3  5  4  2

>>> a
   4  0  1  2  3
0  1  1  2  3  4
1  2  2  3  5  4
```

Comment: And, of course, this column actually comes from another dataframe and the label isn't changing, so I can just join it directly. Probably could have done that with `concat` too. We should *totally* have a badge for x/y problem.

Answer (score 0):

And, use `join` and `series`

```
In [870]: a.join(pd.Series([1,2], name=6))
Out[870]:
   4  0  1  2  3  6
0  1  1  2  3  4  1
1  2  2  3  5  4  2

In [871]: a
Out[871]:
   4  0  1  2  3
0  1  1  2  3  4
1  2  2  3  5  4
```

**Or,** another hacky way using `assign` is to rename string columns to int

```
In [892]: a.assign(**{'6': [1,2]}).rename(columns=pd.to_numeric)
Out[892]:
   4  0  1  2  3  6
0  1  1  2  3  4  1
1  2  2  3  5  4  2
```